# How to bind click event with jQuery autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I am creating a searchbox by using jQuery autocomplete.I want to trigger a `click` event when I click on a corresponding `li` from the autocomplete list. I am writing as:

```
  $('.ui-menu-item').click(function(){
                 $('.college').trigger('click');
  });
```

But It is not working. any Idea ?
jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hn838/

Comment: Does `$('.college').click();` not work?

Comment: Could you post a JSFiddle of what you have?

Comment: Your code should work plenty fine. What kind of element is `.college`?

Comment: @lan .college is a div, in which I have a click event, but It is not firing in case of $('.ui-menu-item'). Otherwise it is working fine.

Comment: Does the handler for `<div class="college"/>` work as expected when you actually click on the div?

Comment: I added a jsfiddle link,plz go through it....

Comment: @lan  can you plz refer jsfiddle....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the time your event binding is executed there will be nothing to bind it to because there has been no `.ui-menu-item` created in the DOM.

You need to code your event as such:

```
$('.ui-autocomplete').on('click', '.ui-menu-item', function(){
    $('.college').trigger('click');
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hn838/4/

Comment: The second parameter doesn't make sense. It should be a selector, not a jQuery object

Comment: @Christopher.Cubells I already updated. It works because it interprets the second parameter as a different `on` overload and passes it as data. This event handler you've is basically just a click handler for `.ui-autocomplete`

Comment: @lan How it should be like ?

Comment: @pandit I updated the answer and fiddle. It was very close, and worked (obviously), but wasn't doing what was intended.

Comment: Excellent - this helped me. I've got a 'combobox' handler in a generic js file, and individual js files for specific pages. This snippet allowed me to add this functionality to my individual pages and customise for a specific task. Thanks.